# Using Google Tasks

Tags: google-apps-script, google-tasks

I am trying to create a task in my calendar from sheets.  I have turned on advanced services and I am able to create task.  The problem is more with the way I am trying to enter the fields or app scripts interface is not recognizing the JSON representation.  Not sure witch.  Please help.  I copied and pasted from the developer page and the script works fine until I try to add something that should work according the developer page.

[image]

I have tried using quotes.  Doesn't work.  Tried just a string with a non date field.  Doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

In your JSON you've forgotten a comma (at the end of line 39)

On line 45 you also have "Tasks.Tasks.Insert", you may have accidentally duplicated the word tasks

Comment: Thanks so much.   I must have deleted it when I add the due field and assumed the copied and pasted part was fine.  Comma worked like a charm.